# Differences in IIS 7.5 - 2008 R2 or Windows 7

Tags: iis-7.5

I normally have Windows Server on my portable for compatability issues while writing code, that is, i get to develop on a portable server. Now i need to update either to 2008 R2 or Windows 7 64 (any flavor) and i am leaning toward windows 7, but i am unsure the true differences between the to IIS's. I do install several IIS objects, such as ASPEmail, ASPPDF, ASPUpload, Lanapsoft Captcha and a few others. They all work well in 2008 R2 and i am concerned that they may or may not work inside of Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you can pretty much replace Vista with Windows 7 and 2008 with 2008 R2 in this article.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/479/iis-70-features-and-vista-editions/

The various controls and libraries you mention should almost certainly work as long as you aren't trying to host many concurrent users due to the request limits.